# SWT - Not using first and second Column with GridLayout

Tags: java, swt, frontend

I'm using SWT, on a desktop application, where I'm using a GridLayout splited by 5 columns and one line, there is a tabble using the top of the space and at the bottom I have 3 buttons, I want to put these 3 botton to the right. Basically jump the two first spaces. I tried using:

```
 GridData gridData = new GridData();
 gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
 gridData.horizontalAlignment= GridData.END;
 CompanyGroup.setLayoutData(gridData);
```

But I realized that this method only align inside the column.

```
Composite rightComp = DialogCompositeFactory.create(parent);
rightComp.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
Group CompanyGroup = DialogGroupFactory.create(rightComp,Message));
CompanyGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, true));
```

Like the example below

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put empty label controls in the first two columns.

```java
// Empty first column
new Label(CompanyGroup, SWT.LEAD);

// Empty second column
new Label(CompanyGroup, SWT.LEAD);

... your buttons in the last three columns
```

Comment: This is a pretty standard thing to do, you have to put something in the columns. The alternative is to use a separate composite as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a composite for buttons, if not create a composite for buttons and set a `GridData` with `HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_END`

```
Composite buttonsComposite = new Composite( groupComp, SWT.NONE );
GridData gd = new GridData( GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_END );
GridLayout lo = new GridLayout(3,true);
buttonsComp.setLayoutData( gd );
buttonsComp.setLayout(lo);
```